# What does $x^2 \geq y^2$ imply?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

What does $x^2 \geq y^2$ imply?

I'm struggling a little on the question I thought of when working another problem.

Do we simply have that if $x^2 \geq y^2$ then $x \geq y$ and nothing else?

Or can we relate $-y$ to $x$ some how. I guess my confusion stems from the fact that $\sqrt {x^2}$ returns only positive $x$.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried some exaples like  $ x= -3 $ and  $ y=2$ ?

Comment: Keep in mind that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.

Comment: I just tried it with those examples. So I guess my original implication doesn't even work. Wow. I thought you could just square root both sides. Now I am very stuck. How can I treat these properly?

Answer (score 4):

You could take the square root of both sides, keeping in mind that $\sqrt{a^2} = |a|$, so:

$$x^2 \ge y^2 \Leftrightarrow |x| \ge |y| $$

What does this mean for $x$ and $y$?

Or, rewrite:

$$x^2 \ge y^2 \Leftrightarrow x^2 - y^2 \ge 0 \Leftrightarrow (x-y)(x+y) \ge 0$$

Can you take it from here?

You could go for a graphical solution as well, drawing the lines $y = x$ and $y = -x$.

Comment: Interesting so if $(x-y)(x+y) \geq 0$ then I suppose you just say either both are positive or both are negative and then you can take it from there?

Comment: That's right: the product is positive (or 0) if both factors are positive (or 0) OR if both factors are negative. Sketch a plane with the lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$ to see what areas in the plane satisfy these conditions. Perhaps you can understand how this relates to $|x| \ge |y|$.

Comment: That first equivalence is very cool! Here's one way of looking at it. Given sets $P$ and $Q,$ a function $f : P \rightarrow Q,$ and a binary relation $\overline{Q}$ on $Q$, define that $f^*(\overline{Q})$ is the binary relation on $P$ defined by $f^*(\overline{Q})(p,p') \iff \overline{Q}(f(p),f(p')).$ Define furthermore that whenever $P$ and $Q$ carry the structure of preordered sets, the *coimage* of $f : P \rightarrow Q$ is $f^*(\geq_Q)$. Then that first equivalence says that the coimages of squaring and absolute value are equal as binary relations on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply any monotonically increasing function to both sides of an inequality, then the inequality still holds: $x \geq y$ implies $f(x) \geq f(y)$. (Actually, this is the definition of an increasing function).

Since $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is an increasing function, $x^2 \geq y^2$ implies that $\sqrt{x^2} \geq \sqrt{y^2}$.

You are right to worry about positives and negatives. $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ (the absolute value of $x$). Thus you have $|x| \geq |y|$.

Anytime you have $|A| \leq B$, then $-B \leq A \leq B$ (Why? $A \geq 0$ yields: $A = |A| \leq B$ and $A <0$ yields: $-A = |A| \leq B$ so that $A \geq -B$).

Using this, you get: $-|x| \leq y \leq |x|$.

This is the region above the negative absolute value function and below the absolute value function ([looks like a bow tie](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%7C%20-abs%28x%29%3C%3Dy%3C%3Dabs%28x%29%20%7C%20x%20%3D%20-5%20to%205%20and%20%20y%20%3D%20-5%20to%205)).

Answer (score 1):

The square of a number is greater than that of another if it is bigger when dropping the signs. In orther words,

$x^2\ge y^2 \Leftrightarrow |x|\ge |y|$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x\geq 0$, then 
$$x\geq y, x\leq -y\qquad\Rightarrow -x\leq y\leq x$$

If $x\leq 0$ then
$$-x\geq y, -x\leq -y\qquad \Rightarrow x\leq y\leq -x$$

[image]