# How to solve $y^2 \ge x^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I decide where to write the minus after taking the square root?

Could someone explain this?

$y^2 \ge x^2$

Comment: The squaring operation? Do you mean after taking the square root?

Comment: yes i edited. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See also: [What does $x^2 \ge y^2$ imply?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1467249/159845)

Recall that $\sqrt{a^2} = |a|$, so:
$$y^2 \ge x^2 \Leftrightarrow |y| \ge |x|$$
Does that help?

---

Alternatively:
$$y^2 \ge x^2 \Leftrightarrow y^2-x^2 \ge 0\Leftrightarrow (y-x)(y+x) \ge 0$$
For a sketch, start with the equality:
$$(y-x)(y+x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow y = x \,\vee\, y = -x$$
So draw those two lines, these divide the plane into 4 parts. Can you find out which parts satisfy the inequality? By reasoning and/or by 'testing' a few points (fill in the coordinates) to get an idea.

Comment: is there a representation without the absolute value?

Comment: See the second part under 'Alternatively', that doesn't use the absolute value.

Comment: I'm asked to draw a graph to of this inequality and to show what are the values on the graph I can get from this inequality. How to do that?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea in my second paragraph ('Alternatively'). I added a bit, does that help?

Comment: yes. I think in the triangle above their intersection and the one under their intersection

Comment: Correct! You may be able to reconnect this with $|y| \ge |x|$ because those are exactly the places in the plane where the absolute value of $y$ is bigger than the absolute value of $x$...!

Answer (score 0):

$$(y^2-x^2)=(y+x)(y-x)\ge0,$$ and both factors must have the same sign. So

$$(y+x\ge0\text{ and }y-x\ge0)\text{ or }(y+x\le0\text{ and }y-x\le0).$$

This can be rewritten

$$(y\ge-x\text{ and }y\ge x)\text{ or }(y\le-x\text{ and }y\le x),$$

or shortly

$$(x\ge-y,y)\text{ or }(x\le-y,y).$$

Lastly, you can rewrite

$$(y\ge-x,x)\text{ or }(-y\ge-x,x),$$

and

$$-y,y\ge-x,x.$$